# Bilinear forms in ${\Bbb R}^3$

Tags: linear-algebra

> Consider $V={\Bbb R}^3$ and bilinear forms $B_k:V\times V\to {\Bbb R}$ $(k=1,2,3)$. Use the hairy ball theorem to show that one can not have $B_1,B_2,B_3$ such that
>   $$
> B_1(x,y)^2+B_2(x,y)^2+B_3(x,y)^2=|x|^2|y|^2
> $$ 
>   for all $x,y\in\Bbb{R}^3$.

What I got so far is the following consequence (which might be possibly useful) *if* such bilinear forms exist:

whenever $u\perp v$ in $\Bbb{R}^3$, and $z\in{\Bbb R}^3$, one has
$$
(B_1(z,u),B_2(z,u),B_3(z,u))\perp (B_1(z,v),B_2(z,v),B_3(z,v)).
$$

I don't see how to make a contradictory continuous tangent vector field on the 2-sphere.

Comment: Hamilton couldn't multiply triplets and neither can we. We can multiply pairs, quadruplets, octets. The norm of the product must be the product of the norms, the equality above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint: If you had them then 
$$x\cdot y \,\colon = ( B_1(x,y), B_2(x,y),B_3(x,y))$$
would give you a normed algebra: $\ \mathbb{R}^3$ with  a bilinear map $\mathbb{R}^3\times \mathbb{R}^3 \to \mathbb{R}^3$ so that 
$$|x\cdot y|^2 = |x|^2 |y|^2$$
Now $\mathbb{R}^2$ is a normed algebra, the multiplication being 
$$(x_1,x_2) \cdot(y_1,y_2) = (x_1 y_1- x_2 y_2,\, x_1 y_2+ x_2 y_1)\ \ \   \text{;-)}$$
You also remember that there were two orthogonal linear vector fields on $\mathbb{R}^2$: $(x_1,x_2) \mapsto (x_1, x_2)$ and $(x_1,x_2) \mapsto (-x_2, x_1)$. Now $(x_1,x_2) = (1,0) \cdot (x_1,x_2)$ and $(-x_2, x_1)= (0,1)\cdot (x_1,x_2)$. This gets us thinking: we might  get a similar thing on $\mathbb{R}^3$, using the hypothetical multiplication $\cdot$

First: let $e\in \mathbb{R}^3$ a unit vector. The multiplication $L_e : x \mapsto e \cdot x$ is an isometry. Indeed: 
$$|e\cdot x|^2 = |e|^2 |x|^2 = |x|^2$$

Second: let $e_1$, $e_2$ unitary and orthogonal vectors. Then $e_1 \cdot x$ and $e_2 \cdot x$ are orthogonal. Indeed, 
$$\langle e_1  x , e_2 x\rangle = \frac{1}{4}(|(e_1+e_2)x|^2 - |(e_1-e_2)x|^2 )= ... =0$$

Now consider an orthonormal basis of $\mathbb{R}^3$. Then for every $x \in \mathbb{R}^3$ of norm $1$ we have the orthonormal basis

$$e_1 x,\  e_2 x,\  e_3 x$$

and so the orthonormal basis

$$x,\  L_{e_1}^{-1}( e_2x),\  L_{e_1}^{-1} (e_3 x)$$

It follows that we have two orthonormal vector fields tangent to the unit sphere

$$L_{e_1}^{-1}( e_2x),\  L_{e_1}^{-1} (e_3 x)$$

Now use that topological argument.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Where is the norm algebra in ${\Bbb R}^2$ from? Looks like the determinant of some matrix.

Comment: @Goku: Can you $\mathbb{C}$ it?

Comment: I don't quite follow your comment. What's more, it seems that one only needs an argument of $e_1x$ and $e_2x$. Would you explain why we need $e_3x$ also?

Comment: Ah, OK, the normed algebra on $\mathbb{R}^2$ is coming for $\mathbb{C}$. For $\mathbb{R}^3$, you need three vector fields that are orthgonal to each other at every point, and so that one of them is the vector field $x\mapsto x$.

Comment: In $\Bbb{R}^3$, starting from $e_1$ and $e_2$, one gets $e_1x$ and $e_2x$ being perpendicular to each other. Then we have $x$ and $L^{-1}_{e_1}(e_2x)$, which give a tangent vector field $x\mapsto L^{-1}_{e_1}(e_2x)$. So $e_3$ is not needed?

Comment: Correct, you get one non-zero vector field using only $e_2$. Perhaps it tells you a bit more, that if $\mathbb{R}^n$ has a structure of a normed algebra then $\mathbb{S}^{n-1}$ is parallelizable, .